# Ladda load animation on a button in input text .change event

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an input type text that is associated with Google API, and a button, when I type something in the input, Google API will start searching for location, while that is done, I want to do some loading animation on my button until the search is complete so I did this:

HTML:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text"  name="r_name" id="autocomplete" placeholder="Code postale, adresse, rue..." 
        onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" style="width:40%;">
    <button href="#" class="btn btn-xl btn-info ladda-button" id="btn"  onclick="displayResto()" style="width:20%;">Chercher <span class="spinner"></span></button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var placeSearch, autocomplete;
  var componentForm = {
    street_number: 'short_name',
    route: 'long_name',
    locality: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name'
  };

  function initAutocomplete() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
    // location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
        {types: ['geocode']});

 
    // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
    // fields in the form.
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
  }

  function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.

    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm) {
      document.getElementById(component).value = '';
      document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
      if (componentForm[addressType]) {
        var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
        document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
      }
    }
  }

   function displayResto()
  { 
    var location = document.getElementById('autocomplete').value;
if(location != "x")
{
    localStorage.setItem('location', location);
    window.location.href = "DisplayResto.html";
}
else
{   

    window.location.href = "NotAvalable.html";

     }

}
```

and this is the js for the ladda activation and deactivation which contains the error:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $('#autocomplete').change(function(){
            var l = Ladda.create('#btn');
    l.start();
     });
     $('#autocomplete').autocomplete(function(){
         var l = Ladda.create('#btn');
    l.stop();
     });

   </script>
```

What have I done wrong?
Thank you

Comment: I have done half of the job by replacing onchagne by keyup function, I want to stop the load when I chose one item from the list that shows by the google api , what can be the jqeury function for that?

Comment: I just added this  var l = Ladda.create(document.getElementById('btn'));
        l.stop();  in the fill in address  function and my problem is solved